# What is the best way to get a callback from an instance of a native C++ class to a C++/CX ref class?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am writing a C++ WinRT Component DLL for use in my .NET-based WinRT application. The DLL defines a SoundSample ref class that creates an XAudio voice by calling [IXAudio2::CreateSourceVoice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.ixaudio2.ixaudio2.createsourcevoice%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). CreateSourceVoice takes a "IXAudio2VoiceCallback *pCallback" parameter to enable callbacks on various audio events. Now I am trying to implement that callback based on [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). XAudio will supposedly just call back into methods of my SoundCallback class defined as:

```
#pragma once
#include "xaudio2.h"
#include "pch.h"

class SoundCallback
    : public IXAudio2VoiceCallback
{
private:
    //SoundSample^ sample; //does not compile

public:
    SoundCallback(void);
    ~SoundCallback(void);

    //Called when the voice has just finished playing a contiguous audio stream.
    void OnStreamEnd();
    void OnVoiceProcessingPassEnd();
    void OnVoiceProcessingPassStart(UINT32 SamplesRequired);
    void OnBufferEnd(void * pBufferContext);
    void OnBufferStart(void * pBufferContext);
    void OnLoopEnd(void * pBufferContext);
    void OnVoiceError(void * pBufferContext, HRESULT Error);
};
```

Everything is fine until I try to figure out how to call back from an instance of my native callback class to the parent SoundSample object. I was thinking I could pass an instance of the SoundSample class to the SoundCallback object, but it seems like it does not allow me to declare a ref class field in the native class:

```
SoundCallback.h(9): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
SoundCallback.h(9): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
SoundCallback.h(9): error C3699: '^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'int'
```

I looked back at implementing callbacks in native C++ and I could not find a reasonable solution so far. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: BTW, if you know of any way to solve it - that would help. I am rather rusty in C++ and the only thing that comes to my mind for now involves having the ref class instance spin up a thread/running on a threadpool thread and wait for threading events coming from the native class - with things like SetEvent, ResetEvent, WaitForSingleObject etc.

Comment: Why is this tagged with C++11?

Comment: I don't know much about C++11, but I would assume that this being a problem of mixing Windows 8 C++/CX and native C++ - there might be some C++ 11 aspects to it...

Comment: ok, though I don't really think "might be" is a sufficient reason for tagging something. With that reasoning, you could tag most C++ post with C++11

Comment: Right, sorry. I guess maybe I was just looking for a wide audience...

Comment: @Ivan: *"Might be"* is good enough of a reason to include a tag. In case someone sufficiently versed in the subject matter determines, that the tag does not apply, they can simply remove it. On the other hand, if the question were asked without the tag, chances for it to get added later are slim. Removing a tag doesn't hurt (not much anyway). Making a Q&A potentially harder to discover, however, is in conflict with this site's spirit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it (thanks to [Jeremiah Morrill](https://twitter.com/#!/jmorrill)) - the problem is not with any barrier blocking the use of ref classes in basic classes. C4430 means that SoundSample is an unrecognized type, which was hidden by Intellisense - since that seemed to indicate that SoundSample is known.
What needs to be added is a declaration of the SoundSample type and this all starts working fine.

I just added

```
namespace MyNamespace { ref class SoundSample; }
```

before the SoundCallback class declaration and then SoundCallback class could declare:

```
MyNamespace::SoundSample^ sample;
```